# jQuery .submit() not submitting on dialog confirm

Tags: jquery

I've gone through several SO articles relating to this issue, but have not found a solution as of yet.  I have a type=submit button, not named/IDed submit, with a listener on the form for the submit call and prompting a box.  The box prompts as expected, the code executes except, instead of $('YYKReservation')[0].submit(); submitting the form as the other answers I've viewed suggest shoudl happen, it changes the form's submit button to a standard submit, i.e. clicking submit again submits the form as usual.  It appears to be unbinding the listener allowing for the submit button to submit but this is confusing for end users.

The form:

```
<form action="reserve.php" method="post" id="YYKReservation" title="YYKReservation">
 ...
<input type="hidden" name="boolConsentM" id="boolConsentM" value="0">
<input name="YYKSubmitM" id="YYKSubmitM" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 ...
    $("#Confirm")
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Prayer Consent',
      zIndex: 10000,
      autoOpen: false,
      width: 'auto',
      resizable: false,
      buttons: {
        Accept: function() {
            $('#boolConsent').val('1');
            
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $('YYKReservation')[0].submit();  //This should submit the form after changing "boolConsent" to 1
        },
        Decline: function() {
            $('#boolConsent').val('0');
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $('YYKReservation')[0].submit(); //This should submit the form after changing "boolConsent" to 0
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });
    
    $('#YYKReservation').submit(function(e) {
        if ($('#boolConsent').val() == 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            $("#Confirm").dialog("open");
        }
    });
});

<div id="Confirm" title="Pray">
    By clicking Accept, ...blah blah
</div>
```

Comment: `$('YYKReservation')[0].submit();` typo -> `$("#YYKReservation')[0].submit();`

Comment: The reason it submits the second time is because your `e.preventDefault` is inside the qualifier #boolConsent == 0, which it doesn't because of `$('#boolConsent').val('1');`.  So second click doesn't get the submit prevented and it submits fine.

Comment: You should simply remove the #boolConsent check in the submit handler so that it always goes via your dialog.  The call`$(..)[0].submit()` will not go via the event handler handler as it's not an "event".  (also fix the missing "#")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector should select the form, ie

```
$('form#YYKReservation')
```

But your selector is literally selecting an element

```
<YYKReservation>
```

That does not exist on your page

Comment: *Why are you using [0]?* you do this in a jquery submit event handler `$("#id").submit()` will re-call the jquery submit handler => infinite loop.   jquery submit() !== javascript submit()

Comment: Ah! That was it.  Another article I was reading didn't have the # on the submit within the button decelarations.  It didn't even don on me to try putting a # there.  @freedomn-m It seems to work fine without the [0] so maybe it's something they've changed recently?  I have to test in a couple different browsers to be 100% though but thanks for the clarification.